# install device on the fly

Tags: winapi, cmd, device, printers

It's possible to install a device on the fly ???

I say device, a printer..., I have the driver, and all things, I just whant to install the device, and, when I close the program, I whant to remove the device.

So, I know, I can use the command RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry to install a printer... ok, I have the driver and all files to install the printer, but, when I go to install I recive  this error ( it's runing with superuser ):

[image: error :(]

The command line I used to install the printer is that:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "Test Printer" /f E:\driver\HP_P2055_default_install_v6.1_ww\hppcp613.inf /r "IP_192.168.0.4" /m "TEST_PRINTER" /Z
```

How I can fix this erro ??
And, How I can install the printe ?

Comment: More appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com/)?

Comment: But this error I have goted with super user :(

Comment: StackOverflow is for ["professional and enthusiast programmers"](http://stackoverflow.com/about), this doesn't appear to be programming question (in my mind at least). SuperUser is for ["computer enthusiasts and power users"](http://superuser.com/about), which seems more appropriate.

Comment: I assumed it was to be done by their program, so valid for SO.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you're not supplying the path to the driver files.  Add the /l parameter with the full-qualified path of where your driver files are.